# The print screen key does not open the screen shot tool in Kubuntu 16.10

Tags: kubuntu, kde

The print screen key does not open the screen shot tool in Kubuntu 16.10.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Kubuntu 16.10 replaces the old screen shot tool [KSnapshot](https://www.kde.org/applications/graphics/ksnapshot/) with [Spectacle](https://www.kde.org/applications/graphics/spectacle/) but does not change the keyboard setting accordingly. Under [System Settings -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts](https://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Shortcuts_and_Gestures#Custom_Shortcuts) the folder "Screenshots" must be developed to show an entry "Start Screenshot Tool". The trigger for this entry must be set to be the print screen key. A dialog will prompt warning that the key is already assigned; it is assigned to KSnapshot; therefore ignore the warning.

Comment: It seems that this is only an issue when updating from Kubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: With this solution only one instance of spectacle is allowed when pressing "print screen". Is there a way to make it open a new instance for each button press?

Comment: `Start screenshot tool` is assigned to the key, however still can't call Spectacle app by `Print` key only manually. Any other ideas?

Comment: What should be the action for this entry?

Comment: I don't have access to my computer now but as far as I can remember the action "Start Screenshot Tool" was already pre-configured when Spectacle is installed. The only missing configuration is the trigger setting (the print screen key).

Comment: I just came home and checked the action "Start Screenshot Tool". Remote application is "org.kde.Spectacle", remote object is "/", function is "StartAgent", arguments is "" (empty). Alternatively the function "FullScreen" will directly take a screenshot of your full screen and the function "ActiveWindow"  will directly take a screenshot of the active window. As I wrote before I never had to input any of this myself, this comes already configured with Spectacle, only the trigger setting (the print screen key) was missing in my case.

Comment: same issue for bionic 18.04

Comment: Simply installing `spectacle` did it for me, some reasonable shortcuts were automatically added to their own category in the "global" shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have changed again in Plasma 5.20+ as per recent Fedora upgrades.  The `print screen` key is assigned to dbus StartAgent command of Spectacle, which actually starts Spectacle in the background and shows nothing (basically useless).  For a fix today you may need to reset the shortcut as per above but I think Spectacle has changed its behavior (v20.12.2 here).

Answer (score 0):

In KDE Neon, Go to **Settings** > **Shortcuts** > **Global Shortcuts** > **KDE Daemon**. You'll find two options named **Take Full Screen Screenshot** and **Take Rectangular Region Screenshot**, press the key area and assign to it the input key you please. This way you'll take a screenshot without having to open *Spectacle* each and every time which is kind of annoying.

Comment: This is a guideline, but not the answer on the questions

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there even was no "Screenshots" folder under "Custom shortcuts"!

Fortunately, those shortcuts can be added from scratch as commands (edit -> new -> global shortcut -> command/url). For example, `spectacle -r -b` is to capture rectangular area, without showing KDE Spectacle window.

Type `spectacle --help` in console to see all available options.