# KSnapshot host is gone / can't take screenshots after update to 16.10

Tags: kubuntu, 16.10, screenshot

i updated my system some days ago from kubuntu 16.04 to 16.10.
now i tried to take a screenshot the software that normally has opend did not - therefore a system message poped up saying: 'ksnapshot host is gone'.

i have tried in the krunner and also in the start menu and konsole to start 'ksnapshot' but it seems it is not installed anymore.

```
$ ksnapshot
The program 'ksnapshot' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install ksnapshot
```

so i tried to install it:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com yakkety InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
stefan@stefan-latitude:~$ sudo apt-get install ksnapshot
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ksnapshot
```

any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Make sure you have all of the default repos enabled: http://i.imgur.com/pJYtYh5.png

Comment: No longer available: http://askubuntu.com/a/837261/589808

Comment: thanks CelticWarrior. that solved my question - so can you add it as answer so i can accept it? or should i delete my question as duplicate somehow? i did not find the other question during my search...