# Print screen key opens default browser on Kubuntu. How to fix?

Tags: kubuntu, 17.10, plasma-5, ksnapshot

If I press the `prt scrn` key on keyboard, a new browser window (chromium) opens with the address pointing to http://ksnapshot/ 
Anyone is experience the same issue?

I'm on Kubuntu 17.10, Plasma Desktop 5.12.2

P.S.: note that `ksnapshot` has been replaced by `kde-spectacle` since December 2015.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per this Q&A: [The print screen key does not open the screen shot tool in Kubuntu 16.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837260/the-print-screen-key-does-not-open-the-screen-shot-tool-in-kubuntu-16-10)

Follow these steps:

Kubuntu 16.10 replaces the old screen shot tool [KSnapshot](https://www.kde.org/applications/graphics/ksnapshot/) with [Spectacle](https://www.kde.org/applications/graphics/spectacle/) but does not change the keyboard setting accordingly. Under [System Settings -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts](https://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Shortcuts_and_Gestures#Custom_Shortcuts) the folder "Screenshots" must be developed to show an entry "Start Screenshot Tool". The trigger for this entry must be set to be the print screen key. A dialog will prompt warning that the key is already assigned; it is assigned to KSnapshot; therefore ignore the warning.